# Tkinter Error when using Entry Delete Method

Tags: methods, tkinter, typeerror, tkinter-entry

In my game, I have an `__init__` function which creates a set of seven entry boxes, like so:

```
self.string1 = StringVal()
self.entry1 = Entry(frame, textvariable = self.string1).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

This is copied six more times. This works.
At the end of the game, though, I want to delete the Entry box's text, using this code I found several places online:

```
self.entry1.delete(0, END)
```

I also tried using something else I found:

```
if self.entry1.get():
    self.entry1.delete(0, END)
```

These both say that `self.entry1` is a `NoneType` object, and has no method `.get()` or `.delete()`. Just to try things out, I substituted `self.entry1.get()` and `self.entry1.delete(0,END)` with `self.string1.get()`, etc. I also tried substituting `.delete(0, END)` with `.delete(0.0, END)`. Neither of these worked either. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Read the first section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12024089/1217270).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
self.foo = Button(...).grid(...)
```

... Then what gets stored in `self.foo` is the result of the call to `grid()`. This will always be `None`. You need to separate your widget creation from the loyout in order to save a reference to the created widgets.

Comment: THANK YOU This worked. I would vote up, but I do not have enough reps. This completely solved the problem. Can you explain why this is though? I don't really understand why this works