# Updating Tkinter Window Label Variable With Data Outside The Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I want to update my tkinter window label with the new variable from the data outside the thread.

Here is my sample code:

```
class App(threading.Thread):
global small
global medium
global large
global jumbo
global reject
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.start()

def callback(self):
    self.root.quit()

def run(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
    string1 = "SMALL: " + str(small) + '\n' + "MEDIUM: " + str(medium) + '\n' + "LARGE: " \
              + str(large) + '\n' + "JUMBO: " + str(jumbo) + '\n' + "REJECTED: " + str(reject) + '\n' + "TOTAL: " + str(total)
    label = tk.Label(self.root, text=string1)
    label.pack()


    self.root.mainloop()
app = App()
#actual code runs outside the App() thread
```

The variables there are being changed by the actual code running outside the thread. I tried using `root.after()` but I cannot make it work.

Comment: ***"I tried using root.after()"***: Can't reproduce this, please make sure, code you posts actually behaves as you claim. Read [how to use after method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632)

Comment: The `label` is a local variable inside `run()` function that cannot be accessed outside the function.

Comment: The indentation in your example needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

After the interpreter runs the line `self.root.mainloop()`, it will be stuck inside an infinite loop. The rest of the code after that line will not be run. So the code that changes all the variables must be before `self.root.mainloop()` or be triggered by buttons.

As to how to set button callbacks, you could refer to [python Tk keeping label text after I set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022082/python-tk-keeping-label-text-after-i-set)